# ng-repeat for json object not working

Tags: angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

This is my html and it would create profiles per reponse it gets from the $http.get service.

```
 <div class="container" ng-controller="profileController" ng-init="loadProfilesData()">
<div ng-repeat="p in profileData">

<div>{{p.company}}</div>
 <div>{{p.country}}</div>

<div gauge-chart class="gauge" id="first-{{p.Id}}" value=p.value*100 min=0 max=100 gauge-width-scale=0.8 title="" 
donut=false relative-gauge-size=true symbol='%' hide-min-max=true></div>




<div gauge-chart class="gauge" id="second-{{p.Id}}" value=p.value*100 min=0 max=100 gauge-width-scale=0.8 title=""  
donut=false relative-gauge-size=true symbol='%' hide-min-max=true></div>






<span>

{{ p.value | date: "hh:mm:ss" }}

</span>
</div>                
  </div>
```

The reponse i get is like below

```
     {
                   ID: "1",
                   employeeList: {
                      [{"Value":0.003,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}},
{"Value":0.004,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"},
{"Value":0.005,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test2","Tag":"Devo102"}]
                   },
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Sales",
                   country: "USA"                  

                },
                {
                   ID: "2",
                   employeeList: null,
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Sales",
                   country: "USA"                  

                },
                {
                   ID: "3",
                   employeeList: [{"Value":0.003,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test0","Tag":"Devo100"}},
{"Value":0.004,"Stat":{"parameter":0,"Name":"test1","Tag":"Devo101"}],
                   comapny: "MSDFT",
                   department: "Sales",
                   country: "USA"                  

                }
```

Since im getting inner list for name, value and sometimes i get this list employeeList empty. Do i need to have another ng-repeat for employeeList. Please suggest how can i bind since ordering is also random.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to have another ng-repeat since **`employeeList`** is an object.

You could just access it like,

```
<div>
    <span>{{p.employeeList.Name }}</span>
    <span>{{p.employeeList.Age}}</span>
    <span>{{p.employeeList.hireDate}}</span>
</div>
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
myApp.controller('profileController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.profilesData = [{
            ID: "1",
            employeeList: {
                Name: "harry",
                Age: "20",
                hireDate: 236558.189280
            },
            comapny: "MSDFT",
            department: "Sales",
            country: "USA"

        },
        {
            ID: "2",
            employeeList: null,
            comapny: "MSDFT",
            department: "Sales",
            country: "USA"

        },
        {
            ID: "3",
            employeeList: {
                hireDate: "",
                Name: "marry",
                Age: ""

            },
            comapny: "MSDFT",
            department: "Sales",
            country: "USA"

        }
    ];

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='myApp'>
    <div class="container" ng-controller="profileController">
                    <div ng-repeat="p in profilesData">
                        <span>{{ p.ID }}</span>
                        <div>
                            <div>{{p.Name}}</div>
                            <div>{{p.Age}}</div>                            
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div>
                            <span>
                            {{ p.hireDate | date: "hh:mm:ss" }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div>
                            <span>Company</span>
                            <span>Department</span>
                            <span>Country</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>{{p.company }}</span>
                            <span>{{p.department}}</span>
                            <span>{{p.country}}</span>
                        </div>
                         <div  ng-if="p.employeeList">
                            <span>{{p.employeeList.Name }}</span>
                            <span>{{p.employeeList.Age}}</span>
                            <span>{{p.employeeList.hireDate}}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks there is a tweak in my requirement, can you help on this please

Answer (score 0):

use `ng-if` to check the property is null or not

```
<div ng-if="p.employeeList">
     <span>{{p.employeeList.Name }}</span>
     <span>{{p.employeeList.Age}}</span>
     <span>{{p.employeeList.hireDate | date: "hh:mm:ss"}}              </span>
</div>
```

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.profilesData = [ {
   ID: "1",
   employeeList: {
      Name: "harry",
      Age:   "20",
      hireDate: 236558.189280
   },
   comapny: "MSDFT",
   department: "Sales",
   country: "USA"                  

},
{
   ID: "2",
   employeeList: null,
   comapny: "MSDFT",
   department: "Sales",
   country: "USA"                  

},
{
   ID: "3",
   employeeList: {
      hireDate: "",
      Name: "marry",          
      Age:   ""

   },
   comapny: "MSDFT",
   department: "Sales",
   country: "USA"                  

}]

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="p in profilesData">
    <span>{{ p.ID }}</span>
    <div>
        <div>{{p.Name}}</div>
        <div>{{p.Age}}</div>                            
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <span>
        {{ p.hireDate | date: "hh:mm:ss" }}</span>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div>
        <span>Company</span>
        <span>Department</span>
        <span>Country</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>{{p.comapny }}</span>
        <span>{{p.department}}</span>
        <span>{{p.country}}</span>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="p.employeeList">
        <span>{{p.employeeList.Name }}</span>
        <span>{{p.employeeList.Age}}</span>
        <span>{{p.employeeList.hireDate | date: "hh:mm:ss"}}              </span>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: thanks there is a tweak in my requirement, can you help on this please

Answer (score 0):

You don't need another `ng-repeat` for these fields. You can access the child JSON object like this: `p.employeeList.hireDate`

If a value might be `null` you could check using `ng-if` and choose whether or not you want to display the HTML.

**Example:**

```
<div ng-repeat="p in profilesData">
    <div>
        <span ng-if="p.employeeList != null">{{ p.employeeList.hireDate | date: "hh:mm:ss" }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Get method</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

 <table>
  <tr>
   <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in result[0]">{{key}}</th>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in result">
   <td ng-repeat="(key, val) in item">{{val}}</td>   
  </tr>
 </table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var data = {
    "records": [
      {
        "Name": "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City": "Berlin",
        "Country": "Germany"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Antonio Moreno Taquería",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Around the Horn",
        "City": "London",
        "Country": "UK"
      },
      {
        "Name": "B's Beverages",
        "City": "London",
        "Country": "UK"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Berglunds snabbköp",
        "City": "Luleå",
        "Country": "Sweden"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Blauer See Delikatessen",
        "City": "Mannheim",
        "Country": "Germany"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Blondel père et fils",
        "City": "Strasbourg",
        "Country": "France"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bólido Comidas preparadas",
        "City": "Madrid",
        "Country": "Spain"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bon app'",
        "City": "Marseille",
        "Country": "France"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Bottom-Dollar Marketse",
        "City": "Tsawassen",
        "Country": "Canada"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Cactus Comidas para llevar",
        "City": "Buenos Aires",
        "Country": "Argentina"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "City": "México D.F.",
        "Country": "Mexico"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Chop-suey Chinese",
        "City": "Bern",
        "Country": "Switzerland"
      },
      {
        "Name": "Comércio Mineiro",
        "City": "São Paulo",
        "Country": "Brazil"
      }
    ]
  }

  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope){
   $scope.result = data.records;
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```